# how to save audio file after record in xcode for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, save, record

noob here and need help from the pros...
i am doing a voice record project where i already know how to record using speak here sample from apple.. but now i want to save the file and create a gallery of all recorded save file in my apps..

please help im a bit stuck..

thanks you so much with all you guys help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@shy i think you will find more info in these links

[iPhone SDK:Saving a streamed audio file to Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423536/iphone-sdksaving-a-streamed-audio-file-to-documents-folder)

[iPhone: how to download media files and save them on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278316/iphone-how-to-download-media-files-and-save-them-on-device)

Comment: just want to know if i record the voice from iphone does the code just like streaming save.. for my project i want to record voice from iphone and save that recorded voice..like recorder in mp3 player.. am i able to do that,,.. thanks

Comment: Yes you can save the recorded data.