# how can i record audio in .3gp format using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios4

I am building an app for iphone and i need to record audio, the docs seem to be missing .3gp format for AVAudioRecorder. Please I need an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 3gp is not an audio format, its a video format.

Comment: so is it possible to record using this format, I'm currently recording using .caf format is it possible to convert this format to .3gp?

Comment: I am not sure that you can convert it on iPhone, may be you should research on this a little.

Comment: thanks! robin maybe i should do a lot of reading.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @vincent for recording audio and saving them you have checkout these question, they have most of the details required for audio recording and stuff like that.

[iPhone: how to download media files and save them on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278316/iphone-how-to-download-media-files-and-save-them-on-device)

[iPhone SDK:Saving a streamed audio file to Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423536/iphone-sdksaving-a-streamed-audio-file-to-documents-folder)